# Being $X_{n}$ distributed Poisson $(\lambda_{n})$.Prove that $X_{n}$ tends in probability to 0 Also being $Y_{n}=nX_{n}$ Prove that $Y_{n}$ tends to 0

Tags: probability, asymptotics

$\lambda_{n}=1/n$
Also you have to prove that they tend to $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$.
By definition $X_{n}$ tends to $0$ in probability when $P(|X_{n}-0|>\epsilon)$ tends to $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty $.
I thought doing this: $P(X_{n}>\epsilon)=1-P(X_{n}<\epsilon)=1-F_{x}(\epsilon)$.

But I´m not sure if I´m in the right path.

Comment: Probably your $\lambda$ should be $\lambda_n$, i.e. some dependence on $n$ is needed in the parameter $\lambda$. Otherwise you can take constant sequence, which would not converge in probability to $0$.

Comment: Without further assumptions on $\lambda_n$ it cannot be true in general.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, now it is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by $Y_n$ tending to $0$? Is this convergence also in probability?

Comment: Yes they both converge in probability

Comment: This is definitelly the right path, you started. Now, if $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$, then $\mathbb P(X_n > \varepsilon) = 1 - \mathbb P(X_n \le \varepsilon) = 1 - \mathbb P(X_n = 0) = 1 - e^{-\lambda_n} = 1 - e^{-\frac{1}{n}} \to 0$, which gives us $X_n \to 0$ in probability. Try similarly with $Y_n$.

Comment: Why you assume that epsilon is between $0$ and $1$? The definition have to be proved to every epsilon greater than zero.

Comment: Note that $E(Y_n) = 1$ such that $Y_n$ cannot converge to $0$ in probability.

Comment: @FrancoMaurino $P(X_n > 1) < P(X_n > \varepsilon)$ for $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ so it only suffices to take $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis and why is that? Sorry I don´t understand

Comment: Because the CDF $F_{X_n}(x) = P(X_n < x)$ is increasing

Comment: But the CDF is increasing for every CDF. So taking $\epsilon$ between zero and one applies to every distribution?

Comment: I thought an answer for the second question. $P(nX_{n}>\epsilon)=1-P(X_{n}<\frac{\epsilon}{n})$. Taking limits to $n$ to infinity this tends to 1.

Comment: @FrancoMaurino Yes, you can do this for every distribution and for every sequence that you want to show that converges in general.